# pip install beautifulsoup causes idp.generic

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I just tried to install beautifulsoup to a python virtual env using `pip install BeautifulSoup` which raised a python syntax error for the files I was trying to install. I subsequently tried `pip install beautifulsoup` which had the same result. Shortly after this, I got an alert from Avast that pip.exe was infected with idp.generic and then that clink_x64.exe (I am using cmder command line on windows) was also infected with idp.generic. I was wondering if this is actually a virus problem I need to resolve or if this is simply just Avast being overly sensitive. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDP generic means: the detection was detected by an Identity Protection detection component and it is a generalized file that got detected. Simply, means that the program behaved in a way that is close to what malware does. This could be a false positive. I suggest doing the following :

1. update the signatures since a false alarm could be raised due to an outdated database.
2. Submit your python.exe to https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload to see what it does report.
3. I found a recent comparative study about false alarms at av-comparatives.org/tests/false-alarm-test-march-2018, read this for better understanding.

In my opinion, it is a false positive.

Comment: Thanks, everything came back without malware detected so your opinion seems correct.